# Move file without opening in django-storages and S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I am using django with django-storages and S3 to manage some uploaded files. These files can be uploaded in an "feature" folder, for example:

/uploads/products/*product_code*/*feature*/*filename*.pdf

and I want to move the files out of this *feature* folder, delete the original file (and eventually the containing folder when all files have been processed) so they can be found at:

/uploads/products/*product_code*/*filename*.pdf

I currently have the following code to do this:

```
def move_files_in_folders(path, folder):
    files = default_storage.listdir(path+"/"+folder)
    returnable_file_list = list()

    for filename in files[1]:
        if filename is not '':

            movable_file = default_storage.open(path+'/'+folder+'/'+filename)
            default_storage.save(path+'/'+filename, movable_file)
            default_storage.delete(path+'/'+folder+'/'+filename)
            returnable_file_list.append(filename)

    default_storage.delete(path + '/' + folder)
    return returnable_file_list
```

This works but it is very slow with long file lists as the system will have to open each file and re-save it.

Is there a way I can refactor this code to avoid the expensive open and save calls?

Comment: would it be an option to use the AWS Command Line Interface? then you would not need to do this moving operations within your python code but cut let a command-line command to the job for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can subclass the S3Boto3Storage class and add a method that copies files from a from_path to a to_path

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MyS3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    def copy(self, from_path, to_path):
        from_path = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(from_path))
        to_path = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(to_path))

        copy_result = self.connection.meta.client.copy_object(
            Bucket=self.bucket_name,
            CopySource=self.bucket_name + "/" + from_path,
            Key=to_path)

        if copy_result['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            True
        else:
            False
```

After that you can create your MyS3Storage object and invoke the copy file using the from and to path.